C++20/23 class template argument deduction: mix of explicit and deduced template arguments?
My template needs two types, one that I expect the caller to explicitly specify, the other which should be deducible by the compiler.  Yet it requires me to specify it. Commenting out the foo2 line results in a clean build.  Is there a way to get the foo2-type variable construction to work?
(The toy example program counts, in a variable of any math type, the number of allocations it makes for you of memory for the explicitly-supplied type.)
#include <cstdlib>

template<class T, class U> class Foo {
public:
    Foo( U* counter_in ) : counter( counter_in ) {};
    U* counter;
    T* Alloc() { *counter += 1; return (T*) malloc( sizeof(T) ); };
};

int iCounter = 0;
Foo<double, int> foo1( &iCounter );
Foo<double> foo2( &iCounter );

int main( int nArg, const char* apszArg[] ) {
    double* pd = foo1.Alloc();
    return 0;
}

Compiler output:
> g++ -std=c++23   -c -o t.o t.cpp
t.cpp:12:11: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
   12 | Foo<double> foo2( &iCounter );
      |           ^
t.cpp:3:34: note: provided for 'template<class T, class U> class Foo'
    3 | template<class T, class U> class Foo {
      |                                  ^~~
t.cpp:12:19: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
   12 | Foo<double> foo2( &iCounter );
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   int*
t.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
t.cpp:15:18: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Foo'?
   15 |     double* pd = foo.Alloc();
      |                  ^~~
      |                  Foo
> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/14/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,m2,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --with-libstdcxx-zoneinfo=/usr/share/zoneinfo --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-14.0.1-20240411/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,amdgcn-amdhsa --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.0.1 20240411 (Red Hat 14.0.1-0) (GCC)


CTAD is a whole or nothing.
You might create a template make_Foo:
template <typename T, typename U>
Foo <T, U> make_Foo(U* u) { return Foo<T, U>(u); }

and then
auto foo2 = make_Foo<double>( &iCounter );


Is there some technical reason it must be all or nothing, or would have been difficult to allow splits?  At first glance it seems pretty straightforward but often restrictions are because allowing the obvious thing would actually result in issues or be impossible in the general case.

Design decision to handle "ambiguity"/edge case. Partial CTAD leads to some ambiguity. Assuming template<typename...Ts> struct Bar;, the conversion Bar<A> b = Bar<A, B>{}; would not be possible (as b would then be Bar<A, B>).  CTAD is already problematic with copy constructor: std::optional o(t) when t is already an optional (so std::make_* are still useful).
